# Android RecycleView with random placed items

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Want to make a list of items, but sorted in different way, like randomly placed. Number of items will be dynamically change, relatively the API. Thing is that, how can i place all incoming items in randomly placed way, exactly like this: ImageSample

[image]

P.S. There are will be 3 types of figures: Horizontal Rectangle, Vertical Rectangle and Square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make multiple view holder pattern and then on basis of specific variable inflate the view inside adapter. As you have 3 types of different rows you have to create 3 viewholders

Comment: Tried it, but i have no idea how to place elements with random number of columns

Comment: What do you mean by random number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [StaggeredGridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) if you don't know hoz to use it, follow this example : 
[Example](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Comment: already tried this, as i know it needs strictly specified numbs of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ArrayList for person names
    ArrayList personNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 6", "Person 7", "Person 8", "Person 9", "Person 10", "Person 11", "Person 12", "Person 13", "Person 14"));
    ArrayList personImages = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.person1, R.drawable.person2, R.drawable.person3, R.drawable.person4, R.drawable.person5, R.drawable.person6, R.drawable.person7, R.drawable.person1, R.drawable.person2, R.drawable.person3, R.drawable.person4, R.drawable.person5, R.drawable.person6, R.drawable.person7));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // get the reference of RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        // set a StaggeredGridLayoutManager with 3 number of columns and vertical orientation
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
        //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the reference and data to Adapter
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, personNames, personImages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // set the Adapter to RecyclerView
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    ArrayList personNames;
    ArrayList personImages;
    Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList personNames, ArrayList personImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personNames = personNames;
        this.personImages = personImages;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // set the data in items
        holder.name.setText(personNames.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageResource(personImages.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // open another activity on item click
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", personImages.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personNames.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // init the item view's
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Open res -> layout -> activity_main.xml (or) main.xml and add following code:

In this step we create a RecyclerView in our XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a new XML file rowlayout.xml for grid item of RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_item_layout"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <!--
    grid items for RecyclerView
    -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ABCD"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: looks great, but here is also 3 columns. in this case i need to place in random number of columns..

Comment: This layout is a grid, with a fixed span. However, we can have items spanning on the whole line or column. Let’s see how it works. Using our active/inactive items from earlier, we’ll make active items fully spanning. This is done in the Adapter, when binding an item.

Comment: // Span the item if active
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams sglp = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
            sglp.setFullSpan(item.isActive());
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(sglp);
        }

Comment: sorry, what type of item you talking about?

Comment: item is just for example if your data item in a cell is active the show in full column view otherwise show in a group of 2 or 3. It depend on your data response.